# Python array strange behavior?

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Case 1:

```
>>> a = [[0]] *3
>>> print a
[[0], [0], [0]]
>>> a[1].append(0)
>>> print a
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Case 2:

```
>>> a = [[0],[0],[0]]
>>> print a
[[0], [0], [0]]
>>> a[1].append(0)
>>> print a
[[0], [0, 0], [0]]
```

Why is this going on? I am expecting that the behavior of the array in case 1 to be as in case 2 but it is not for some reason.

Comment: Shallow copy in first case?

Comment: Note that these are Python `list`s, not arrays. In the context of Python, `array` is usually interpreted to mean a NumPy array (though there's also a standard library `array` module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you are creating a list `[0]` and duplicate it 3 times. This is the same object repeated three times. You should use the star form only with immutable type

To avoid this issue when you have a mutable type, use list comprehension:

```
a = [[0] for _ in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

In the first case, the three elements in `a` actually reference to the same list objects. You can check their id:

```
>>> id(a[0])
4524132472
>>> id(a[1])
4524132472
>>> id(a[2])
4524132472
```

Comment: Or alternatively, `(a[0] is a[1]) == True`